# AngularJS Unit testing a link in a directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write unit tests to test my directives. However, when I invoke a click on a checkbox, it will not update the model.

How can I make it change the model? Somehow it doesn't seem to bind.

**When I remove the directive, and just use a plain checkbox bound to a scope var, the same behavior as below is found. (So this is not specifically a problem for directives)**

Spec function:

```
describe('validationGroup directive',function(){
    var elm,scope;
    beforeEach(function(){
        //Create a scope
        scope.who = {};
        scope.who.selfIncluded = true;
        scope.who.othersIncluded = false;

        //Compile basic form
        inject(function($compile) {
            elm = angular.element('<div ng-form="testFormName" validation-group="groupName">' +
                '<input id="check1" type="checkbox" atleast-one-insured ng-model="who.selfIncluded" ng-change="update()">' +
                '<input id="check2" type="checkbox" atleast-one-insured ng-model="who.othersIncluded"ng-change="update()">' +
              '</div>');
            elm = $compile(elm)(scope);
        });
        scope.$digest();
    });

    //Test the basic form we compiled
    it("Should manipulate the model",function(){
        var cb0 = elm.find("input").eq(0);
        expect(scope.who.selfIncluded).toBeTruthy(); // Succeeds
        cb0.triggerHandler('click');
        scope.$digest(); // probably not necesarry
        expect(scope.who.selfIncluded).toBeFalsy();  // Fails
    });
});
```

Comment: hmm, I can't say anything about click not working, but it seems like you are testing angular core functionality here. A click triggers ng-change, but this has nothing do to with your application logic, you don't have to test this again.

Comment: Apart from that, there's a utility called browserTrigger built in angular.js that emulates events. Have your tried that?

Comment: There's stuff happening inside the directive (code not posted here) that I want to test. Before that piece of code works correctly, atleast the basics should be running as expected.

Comment: @Narretz browserTrigger is part of angular-scenario.js I just tried to use that, and it works! Thanks man :) You might want to post it as the answer for readability to others reading this q&a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, angular-scenario has a utility called browserTrigger that works well for angular app testing:

```
browserTrigger(element,'click');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think you could simply replace:

```
cb0.triggerHandler('click');
```

with:

```
cb0.trigger('click');
```

As `triggerHandler` does not trigger the **true browser event**, just **executes all handlers** attached to an element for an event.